# Start a process without hanging my workflow on VB.NET / C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, process, thread-priority

I'm trying to build a "loader" - means, a program that will launch some predefined programs when I'll run it.
The issue is that I don't want the launched programs to interrupt my workflow, and **for every program there is 0-2 seconds of "hanging"**.

```
            If showLog = True Then Console.WriteLine("Starting --->" + "Skype")
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe"
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/nosplash /minimized"
            proc.Start()
            proc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal
```

I thought that I might be able to start the process on **"Idle" or "BelowNormal" priority**.
But I can only set that priority **after the program is loaded - which is too late**.

Any idea?

Note that everything is working but **the problem is the little "Freeze" duration** - that becomes major when there are more than few programs loaded.

Thanks.

Comment: I think its not possible with the surfaced API in .NET. You need to P/Invoke on CreateProcess and start the process suspended. Then set its priority before resuming.

Comment: When you step through with the debugger, which line does it hang on? Also why do you need to set the priority? They're [evil don't ya know?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/thread-priorities-are-evil.html) ;)

Comment: Do you mean your GUI freezes? Have you tried threads?

Comment: How about creating a *Task* and starting your process in it? c# example:`Task.Run(() =>{ /*your code to start a process*/ });`

Comment: Ha, always knew not to trust priorities :)
Yeap, I mean that the GUI freezes for short amount of time.
I'm not so familiar with tasks in .net, but why should it prevent the GUI freeze? and wouldn't it kill the task when the program end?

I'll try to dig into the first suggestion about starting the process suspended.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to launch Skype with cmd /c start /low executable.exe parameters, this would complete after skype.exe is launched, you could then retrieve the new Skype.exe process by name.

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c start /low ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe"" /nosplash /minimized"
proc.Start()
proc.WaitForExit()
proc = (From p In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("skype.exe") Order By p.StartTime Descending).FirstOrDefault()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Mike Drucker** I've done it:

(ProcessName = The execute file name without ".exe" - "skype.exe" ===> "skype")

```
Private Sub StartProcessAndNormalize(Path As String, ProcessName As String, Optional Args As String = "", Optional PrintLog As Boolean = False)
    If PrintLog = True Then Console.WriteLine("Starting --->" + ProcessName)
    StartCmdProcess(Path, Args, ProcessName)
    ProcessBackToNormal(ProcessName)
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessBackToNormal(ProcessName As String)
    Dim proc As Process
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    proc = (From p In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName) Order By p.StartTime Descending).FirstOrDefault()
    Try
        proc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Normal
    Catch
        Console.WriteLine("Can't find process " & ProcessName)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub StartCmdProcess(Path As String, Args As String, Optional ProcessName As String = "")
    Dim proc As Process = New Process
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c   start """ & ProcessName & """ /BelowNormal """ & Path & """ " & Args
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    proc.Start()
    proc.WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

and we use it like this:

```
StartProcessAndNormalize("C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe", "Skype", "/nosplash /minimized", showLog)
```